# dplyr::select Passing a range of variables to wrapper function containing dplyr::select

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to create a function that selects columns using `dplyr`'s `select` and then applies an arbitrary functions over the rows of the selected columns.

Here's my attempt:

```
aggregate <- function(Df, selection, fun=sum){
  select(Df, selection) %>% apply(1, fun)
}
```

It works fine with the `select` helpers:

```
set.seed(42)
N <- 10
Df <- tibble(p_1 = rnorm(N),
         p_2 = rnorm(N),
         q_1 = rnorm(N),
         q_2 = rnorm(N))

# mean over p_1 and p_2
aggregate(Df, starts_with('p'), mean)

# max over p_1 and q_1
aggregate(Df, ends_with('1'), max)

# sum over p_1, p_2, q_1, q_2
aggregate(Df, everything())
```

However, while we could do

```
select(Df, p_1:q_2) %>% apply(1, mean)
```

this does not work

```
aggregate(Df, p_1:q_1, mean) 

 Error in overscope_eval_next(overscope, expr) : object 'p_1' not found
```

I've read http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html in search of some insight into whether this can be solved but can't see the solution or see even if there is a solution that would allow me to use the e.g. "p_1:q_1" case as well as the e.g. "starts_with('p')" case.

Comment: Use `!!rlang::enquo(selection)` instead of `selection` in the body of your function definition.

Comment: If you don't, `select` will first look for a variable called `selection` in `Df`. If it isn't found, it'll look in the calling environment, where it is defined: in the case where you use select helpers, it produces a valid result due to the way `tidyselect` registers variables. However, if you use `p_1:q_1` you look for the objects `p_1` and `q_1` in the calling environment, which aren't defined: thus the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by [Mikko Marttila](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4550695/mikko-marttila), I *think* it is as simple as using `enquo` and `!!`.

```
library(tibble)
library(rlang)
library(dplyr)

aggregate <- function(Df, variable_selection, fun=sum){
  .variable_selection <- enquo(variable_selection)
  select(Df, !!.variable_selection) %>% apply(1, fun)
}


set.seed(42)
N <- 10
Df <- tibble(p_1 = rnorm(N),
             p_2 = rnorm(N),
             q_1 = rnorm(N),
             q_2 = rnorm(N))
```

These work fine as before:

```
aggregate(Df, starts_with('p'), min)
aggregate(Df, ends_with('_1'), max)
aggregate(Df, everything(), mean)
```

And this works fine now too.

```
aggregate(Df, p_1:q_1, max)
```